# Android Pie: How do I open an empty doc file programmatically?

Tags: android

I have an app, where user should be able to open an empty doc file, but I am not able to get it to work with the Intent's available. I tried the below but it doesn't open a blank document, it just prompts me to enter the file name of the doc, same behaviour with Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT.

```
        String mimeType = 
         "application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
                .setDataAndType(null, mimeType);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "untitled");
```

Comment: To create a document, use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: @CommonsWare The behaviour is same with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT as well. it doesn't open an empty doc.

Comment: It is not supposed to open an empty doc. It is supposed to create an empty doc. You would use the `Uri` to fill in the content. If you are looking to start a Microsoft app, and have it open an empty doc, you would need to look up what sort of API Microsoft's apps offer for this sort of thing.

Comment: Can the user choose an app for a .doc file with filesize 0? If yes, then which app refuses to open the doc?(ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).